# Creating structure names using a for loop?

Tags: c++, data-structures

How i could take this structure and create 32 different team names for it?

The stucture to fill:

```
typedef struct team{
    int stats[4];
}Team;
```

This is the text file:

```
patriots 300 200 500 200
rams 200 340 230 300
cardinals 300 200 450 150
...
```

To instantiate 32 instances of Team seems redundant, e.g.:

```
Team patriots;
Team rams;
Team cardinals;
...
```

How to create those instances so I could identify them by their name?

*(see last comment in the snippet to see where I am going wrong)*

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    for(i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++){

        // Read the name
        string name;
        fscanf(file, "%s", name)

        // Create an instance of Team by its name
        /* PROBLEM : Obviously this does not work, 
                     how to name a variable as this? */
        Team name;

        for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            fscanf(file, "r", &name.stats[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I was wondering if i could do something like this" - which is... ?

Comment: Why not add a `std::string` to the struct as a member and store the team name there? And also, use stream operators instead of type unsafe `c`-style `fscanf`.

Comment: Your second `fscanf` format string is malformed.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: Maybe just reading behind that line of text and you see the `something`. Not trying to downvote you but due to this people tend to add to the problem which is descripted here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275765/4003869 . Have upped the question.

Comment: Your question is tagged C++ but you're using `fopen` and `fscanf`. I question your sanity.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: Maybe you could tell why this isn't correct, more over because the OP already has said (s)he is relative new to programming.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to consider an `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` to hold your data.

These allow you to map from a name (e.g., `Rams`) to some associated data (the stats, in your case).

```
std::map<std::string, team> data;
```

This lets you (for one example) treat `data` like an array that's indexed by a string, so you can do things like:

```
std::string team_name;
team temp_team;

std::cin >> team_name >> temp_team;

data[team_name] = temp_team;
```

This isn't usually the *most* efficient way to do things (it can be a bit slow, and use more memory than alternatives) but it's convenient and performance is often much more than adequate.

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly at the point where people need `Array`.

Create an array of length 32.

```
Team teams[32];
```

Then:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++){
    string name;
    fscanf(file, "%s", name);
    for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
        fscanf(file, "%d", &teams[i].stats[j]);
    }
}
```

Note: If you want to use team names, then you can add a new string field to the struct, then you can assign it after reading from file.

Comment: Okay thanks and your note at the bottom makes since

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since you are declaring a string called name. So that variable name already exists when you are trying to declare a Team.

Add instead a string to the object Team and then write the name from the file into the instance of Team.

Since you have thirtytwo teams, create an vector to hold all of them.

You could also create the Team::stats as a vector so you can have different number of scores of each team (to later on maybe to extend it with a date of that score and which team they played against).

```
typedef struct team
{
    std::string name;
    int stats[4];
} Team;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::vector<Team> teams;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    for(i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
    {

        Team team;

        fscanf(file, "%s", team.name)

        for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)
            fscanf(file, "r", team.stats[j]);

        teams.push_back( team );

    }

}
```